# split the name and put it as sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I want to split my name and put my sheet name as splited name

for example: Rohit-Singh My sheet name should be "Singh" I have wirte the code that is put full name as sheet sheet. can any please help me on this

```
Sub dd()

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: And your problem is...(?)

Answer (score 1):

You apparently want to use the `Worksheet_Change` event.  You should add some error handling when renaming worksheets and turn off `Application.EnableEvents` if you are changing values from this event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = Split(Range("A1"), "-")(1)

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "The name must be delimited using a ""-"" and no other special characters can be used", vbInformation, "Action Cancelled"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("A1") = ""
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` function to separate first from last name and assign results to an array. Then use second element to name your workbook.

```
Sub test()
 Dim MyArray() As String
 Dim name As String
    name = "Rohit-Singh"
    MyArray() = Split(name, "-")
    Debug.Print MyArray(0)
    Debug.Print MyArray(1)
End Sub
```